# Enable custom SQL Parameters in PHPStorm

Tags: sql, parameters, phpstorm, inject

I followed the [official tutorial](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/11/database-language-injection-configuration/) to enable custom SQL Parameters, but I wasn't able to get them to work.
I'm using the current version 8.0.3

[image]

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: I think you cannot see it in the screenshot, but the parameter %asd is not recognized as a parameter. It shows a SQL error instead.

Comment: Technically it was recognized -- if you disable "Use in other language string literals" option you will see actual SQL Syntax error instead. Right now the warning is about "Unable to resolve table %asdf" -- this inspection can be disabled.

Comment: No, sadly it does not work. The error says "<comma join expression> expected, got '%'"

Comment: Will it be better if you put `\ ` in front of `%` in custom patterns? That's how it is here on my computer and it works (8.0.3 on Windows 7)

Comment: That does not work eighter. I think the problem is not the pattern, because none of the patterns seem to work

Comment: Well .. it works for me for sure: http://postimg.org/image/p1xbtgmop/ ; http://postimg.org/image/44g0lglnl/ What SQL Dialect it is? For me it's MySQL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79124/discussion-between-0x6368-and-lazyone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first RegEx in the list was `?\d+` which broke all the others. I had to escape the `?`. The correct RegEx is `\?\d+`.

Comment: doesn't work in phpstorm 9.0.1, 9.0.2.  With mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.

Comment: I guess one of your regular expressions is wrong and causes all the others to fail as well. Can you post which one you have in your list?

Comment: By default...  `?\d+, :\w+, %\w+, $\{[^$\{\}]*\}, $\w+$, #\w+#` (i tried `\?\d+` without success)